# Internal storage in android?

Tags: android, file

I am storing my app data to /data/data/com.cuelearn.main/app_Chapters/areas_and_volumes.pdf
is it accesible by the user from the file manager?
Because i want my files not to be used by the user other than in the app?
Please answer?

Comment: As it says "You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed." at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: As I know, such locations are accessible only on rooted devices..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data stored in /data/data// are only accesible by the app itself.
However, users with rooted devices can access the whole file system, so they will be able to open the files.

Comment: If your files are critical, you may encrypt it. Else, a rooted user that have changed the files is on his own responsability.